# How as items listbox Horizontal Alignment Center?

Tags: wpf

A have listbox

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="{Binding name_trainer}" Tag="{Binding idPersonTrainer}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: ListBox.HorizontalContentAlignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding yourstuff}" FontSize="72"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is right, however I needed a bit more:
not only to center, but also to **horizontally stretch the items**. Just changing HorizontalAlignment to Stretch didn't work, so, here's how it's done:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to center the `DockPanel`, rather than the data inside it.  I've seen this behavior with `StackPanel`, because the panel shrinks to the contents.  The centering ends up working properly, but in the wrong context.

Comment: dockpanel, too, is not centered

Comment: @simply: Sorry, was just a guess :)